# record an $id for a parent form as a reference for a response form to Display and INSERT

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/xysxD/11/

if you check the jsfiddle

1. Will have a comment text that slide toggle a response comment?
2. The comment text is inside  tags
3. How can I let the response comment form know to what parent comment is it responding at the time of submission?
4. Do i have to record that data at the moment it slide toggles or at the submission time?
   Modify message

Comment: Jeremy Thanks for editing the post I was editing when you have already edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some hidden input to the id of the comment you're replying to when the comment form slides down.

Comment: it will be trigger after sliding ? because the variable is dead before sliding toggle. if you know what I mean by dead. I gues it is after sliding the toggle right. If so that means I will have to send the id $(this).nextAll(".commentForm:first").slideToggle(); some where in this line

Comment: I will check if I can print the id of each comment which means I can pick it up

Comment: o yes I can echo the id which mean I can use let me see how

Comment: Jethro I did a vardump on POST and the variable name="replyCommentID" is comming empty. which it means that the value of the input field is empty but with jquery and html mixt I don't kwno what to put in there. the $id on the server is echoing but somehow when mix with jquery and then the form it will lose its value.

Comment: what do you mean by value="-1"